# Embedded Excel 16 Window In WPF is not focusable

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I try to embed excel 16 (office 365) window inside WPF application. It is working perfect with Win32 api, but for some strange reason, after opening context menu with right button click from embedded excel file, focus can't be set on any cell anymore.

Moreover, focus start working very strange and no tricks can't set focus back to embedded file.

Maybe someone have experience with this issue and can help to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I attach small test solution which can be use to reproduce the issue by this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LMcrSISzVB7rmoDIXHFspyjeUGrovpl4